# Facebook C# SDK Token Refresh Challenge

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I have a Flash-based iframe app that makes an initial auth call using CanvasAuthorizer.Authorize(). The Flash app then uses web services from then on, no page refreshes occur.

Here's the challenge of this situation:

- There will be no page refreshes, so
  what is the best way to refresh the
  auth token when it expires?
- I can use the JS SDK FB.getLoginStatus call to update the
  cookie, but the FacebookWebContext
  doesn't read from the cookie, it
  reads from the session.

Any Facebook C# SDK gurus here that have run into this?

Regards,

Dave

Comment: I think I may have a solution to this problem here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849234/updating-signed-request-using-javascript-oauth-2-0-sdk

Answer (score 0):

As i know you don't need to refresh the Token, it will expire only if the user removes your app of his profile-settings.

At least this is how it works for offsite applications.

Comment: The token will expire, generally within 2 hours. Unless you request "offline_access", which most people find creepy. I don't want to go there.