# Updating Signed Request using Javascript OAuth 2.0 SDK

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

With the release of the new Javascript SDK and OAuth 2.0, I was wondering if it's possible to update the SignedRequest (and authtoken) without redirecting the user, so I used the following approach. Basically, this is a keep-alive approach for my app to get around the 2 hour expiration window of tokens.

My app consists of:

1. A flash front end + Javascript
2. Web Services (asmx) using Facebook C# SDK

To update the signed request, I do the following:

1. Every 20 seconds I call FB.getLoginStatus using getTimeout()
2. This returns a new signedRequest
3. I update my ajaxSetup to include this parameter on every call to my server.

   ```
   var signedRequest;
   function updateSignedRequest(_signedRequest) {
       signedRequest = _signedRequest;
       $.ajaxSetup({ data: { "signed_request": signedRequest} });
   }
   (function ensureAuth() {
       setTimeout(function () { checkAuth(); ensureAuth(); }, 20000);
   })();
   function checkAuth() {
       FB.getLoginStatus(handleResCallback, true);
   }
   function handleResCallback(res) {
       if (!res.authResponse) {
           handleNotConnected();
       } else {
           signedRequest = res.authResponse.signedRequest;
       }
   }
   ```

A couple questions:

I believe the Facebook C# SDK looks at the `signed_request` parameter on each new request, not the cookie. Will this always be the case?

Also, any other holes you can see in this approach?

Comment: I think that yes because the sdk is working within Facebook context which mean that the cookie can work with non changeable data [may be] it is like an object walking with all of the application 
and the question is not clear why you do not want to look in the sigend request

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best approach for the user. If they have logged out or fail auth for any reason, you will need to handle it by presenting a pop up, or redirecting them to log in. This means they will be interrupted from what they are doing at a random time - rather than waiting for them to do something which requires the authentication, and then presenting the login etc. You could also subscribe to auth events instead of checking every 20 seconds. You will be able to set your handleNotConnected() as the callback when they deauth the app or sign out. Or, you could read the expiry time of the token, and only renew after the expiry time has passed.